# Example of using operator for filter in dataweave 2

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am using dataweave 2 for transformation. I need to use filter operator to filter payload depending upon the value in the request body. The reason for using 'using' is because the value is optional and in that scenario I do not want to filter the payload. My transformation -

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
fun toDate(v) = (v as String{format:'yyyy-MM-dd'} as Date) default null
---
    
if (payload is Array)
    flatten (
        payload **//need to put 2 filters here on  $.CloudAccountDetail.status and $.CloudAccountDetail.clouAccountId //**  map (item, order) -> (
            flatten ( [
                item.NamedSubscriptions map {
                    key: $.SubscriptionId,
                    expiryDate: toDate($.ExpiryDate)
                    //nextPaymentDate: toDate($.NextPaymentDueDate)
                } 
                , 
                item.UnnamedSubscriptions map {
                    key: $.SubscriptionId,
                    expiryDate: toDate($.ExpiryDate),
                    cloudPublicName: item.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountPublicName,
                    cloudAccountId: $.EskoCloudAccount
                }
            ] )
        )  
    )
else []
```

Input -

```
[
  {
    "CloudAccountDetail": {
      "CompanyCode": "B_B001",
      "CloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
      "CloudAccountPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
      "Status": "SUBSCRIBED",
      "ClusterName": "ci.dev.cloudi.city"
    },
    "NamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "8f724cc9-bb21-43bc-8911-94d267eb7917",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": "eskododp03@yahoo.be",
        "AssignedBy": "LicenseService",
        "AssignedDate": "2020-01-07T11:16:52.723",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "5c06112a-90a4-4e76-b2f4-bd19a1ce92b3",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "a258a7fc-cff6-4b53-b19d-4e25a8dbcee6",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "e30f16af-de60-4b84-bdae-aa7b6523c316",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "5ee9eeb6-9d65-42b8-b594-68c9528ff25b",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:20.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "818b38f1-0a10-45dc-ae16-f7d804b31cbc",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:20.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "cf5fc421-8ee0-4f1f-a1ca-e64daef2e0c6",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:20.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "UnnamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "c56c5d21-83dd-4df5-851c-52fd5686240b",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "1d5bf54c-e812-4c17-830d-d3a1104d66a5",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "fbe0bbef-3cc2-451a-9866-0bb31a829850",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "368fa144-5a94-4ead-ba69-502ca6419de4",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "3404fb6e-d234-4dac-a5a1-96c7534ccf21",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:03.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "71d88ad6-3108-499e-8be9-3638c7298770",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:03.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "992b551e-1499-4971-bc9b-34075820faa7",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:03.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "StorageSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "5ceae026-5c3e-40df-a9f8-2de4f4570566",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StorageInGb": 50,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-07T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:37:12.697",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-ST-ST50",
        "ProductName": "Storage Tier 1 (50GB)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "TransactionSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "6eaf4b93-8fef-4423-88fd-7e83d790f6f7",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "NumberOfTransactions": 12000,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-07T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:17:56.257",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-BTR-BTR1000",
        "ProductName": "Basic Transactions Tier 2 (1000/m)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CloudAccountDetail": {
      "CompanyCode": "B_B001",
      "CloudAccountId": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
      "CloudAccountPublicName": "Test-Tom-Desmet",
      "Status": "TRIAL",
      "ClusterName": "ci.dev.cloudi.city"
    },
    "NamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "3dc289af-d469-4dba-875e-354c75d2a31a",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:21:34.773",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": "eskododp03@yahoo.be",
        "AssignedBy": "LicenseService",
        "AssignedDate": "2020-06-30T13:31:01.777",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "3e6818fb-1c4f-4046-9783-5b76d3050eec",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:21:35.773",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "UnnamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "baf3d5c7-b53e-460e-93a5-311b95924fca",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T15:18:15.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "69071fd1-59b5-44ef-a594-95141d68ef4c",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T15:18:16.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "StorageSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "f6f444e3-4dea-43d9-afc0-19d24200cf46",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StorageInGb": 50,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-06-30T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:57:54.05",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-ST-ST50",
        "ProductName": "Storage Tier 1 (50GB)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "TransactionSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "22d25390-4183-4c89-8461-38ebf048812f",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "NumberOfTransactions": 12000,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-06-30T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:24:10.017",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-BTR-BTR1000",
        "ProductName": "Basic Transactions Tier 2 (1000/m)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output I need after transformation. Just take note I have not considered filtering in the ouput. -

```
[
  {
    "key": "8f724cc9-bb21-43bc-8911-94d267eb7917",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "5c06112a-90a4-4e76-b2f4-bd19a1ce92b3",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "a258a7fc-cff6-4b53-b19d-4e25a8dbcee6",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "e30f16af-de60-4b84-bdae-aa7b6523c316",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "5ee9eeb6-9d65-42b8-b594-68c9528ff25b",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "818b38f1-0a10-45dc-ae16-f7d804b31cbc",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "cf5fc421-8ee0-4f1f-a1ca-e64daef2e0c6",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "c56c5d21-83dd-4df5-851c-52fd5686240b",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "1d5bf54c-e812-4c17-830d-d3a1104d66a5",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "fbe0bbef-3cc2-451a-9866-0bb31a829850",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "368fa144-5a94-4ead-ba69-502ca6419de4",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "3404fb6e-d234-4dac-a5a1-96c7534ccf21",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "71d88ad6-3108-499e-8be9-3638c7298770",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "992b551e-1499-4971-bc9b-34075820faa7",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "3dc289af-d469-4dba-875e-354c75d2a31a",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09"
  },
  {
    "key": "3e6818fb-1c4f-4046-9783-5b76d3050eec",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09"
  },
  {
    "key": "baf3d5c7-b53e-460e-93a5-311b95924fca",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09",
    "cloudPublicName": "Test-Tom-Desmet",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "69071fd1-59b5-44ef-a594-95141d68ef4c",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09",
    "cloudPublicName": "Test-Tom-Desmet",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much cleaner example. Instead of using flatten, try using a `function` to populate the values.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
var accountStatus=["SUBSCRIBED"]
var accountId=["a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"]
fun getData(items, account, isUnnamedSubscriptions) = 
    (items default []) map {
        "key": $.SubscriptionId,
        "expiryDate": $.ExpiryDate as Date,
        ("cloudPublicName": account.CloudAccountPublicName) if (isUnnamedSubscriptions),
        ("cloudAccountId": account.CloudAccountId) if (isUnnamedSubscriptions)
    }

output application/json
---

(payload[?((accountId contains $.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountId) 
    and (accountStatus contains $.CloudAccountDetail.Status) )] map (
        getData($.NamedSubscriptions, $.CloudAccountDetail, false)
        ++
       getData($.UnnamedSubscriptions, $.CloudAccountDetail, true)
) flatMap () -> $) default []
```

`accountId` variable is an Array and you can replace that as a string as well and similar to `status` in line `2` and line `3`.

If you have multiple accountId to filter, just add another string in the `accountId`, same as the `status`.

If you want to exclude filter if the CloudAccountDetail.Status is Null and CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountId is Null

You can create a function to return boolean. the funciton should be like this

```
fun isValidFilter(id, stat) = 
    if ( id !=null and stat != null) 
       ((accountId contains id) and (accountStatus contains stat))
    else (true)
```

and the pass the value to the function `isValidFilter`

Example:

```
payload[?( (isValidFilter($.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountId, 
  $.CloudAccountDetail.Status)) )] map ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Ray. But my problem is if accountStatus = null and accountId = null (means value are not present) then I do not need filtration based on these 2 values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Ray. But my problem is if accountStatus = null and accountId = null (means value are not present) then I do not need filtration based on these 2 values.

Comment: You can have use a default. Example:

Comment: You can create a function to return boolean. the funciton should be like this 


fun isValidFilter(id, stat) = 
    if ( id !=null and stat != null) ((accountId contains id) and (accountStatus contains stat)) else (true)

and the formula for payload would be:

payload[?((isValidFilter($.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountId,$.CloudAccountDetail.Status)) )] map
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first apply the filter on the whole array, and then do the rest of the transformation:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
fun toDate(v) = (v as String{format:'yyyy-MM-dd'} as Date) default null
var status = 'SUBSCRIBED'
var accountId = 'a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024'
---
if (payload is Array)
  flatten(payload filter ($.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountId == accountId and $.CloudAccountDetail.Status == status) map(item, value) -> 
flatten ( [
                item.NamedSubscriptions map {
                    key: $.SubscriptionId,
                    expiryDate: toDate($.ExpiryDate)
                    //nextPaymentDate: toDate($.NextPaymentDueDate)
                } 
                , 
                item.UnnamedSubscriptions map {
                    key: $.SubscriptionId,
                    expiryDate: toDate($.ExpiryDate),
                    cloudPublicName: item.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountPublicName,
                    cloudAccountId: $.EskoCloudAccount
                }
            ] ))
else []
```

The above dataweave expression applied to the provided input results in:

```
[
  {
    "key": "8f724cc9-bb21-43bc-8911-94d267eb7917",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "5c06112a-90a4-4e76-b2f4-bd19a1ce92b3",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "a258a7fc-cff6-4b53-b19d-4e25a8dbcee6",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "e30f16af-de60-4b84-bdae-aa7b6523c316",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "5ee9eeb6-9d65-42b8-b594-68c9528ff25b",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "818b38f1-0a10-45dc-ae16-f7d804b31cbc",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "cf5fc421-8ee0-4f1f-a1ca-e64daef2e0c6",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "c56c5d21-83dd-4df5-851c-52fd5686240b",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "1d5bf54c-e812-4c17-830d-d3a1104d66a5",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "fbe0bbef-3cc2-451a-9866-0bb31a829850",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "368fa144-5a94-4ead-ba69-502ca6419de4",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "3404fb6e-d234-4dac-a5a1-96c7534ccf21",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "71d88ad6-3108-499e-8be9-3638c7298770",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "992b551e-1499-4971-bc9b-34075820faa7",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier. But here I am interested in conditional use of filter. I need filter only and only if status and accountId have any value. If they are null then I do not need filter. 'using' can be used here but I am struggling to use that.

Comment: I see. Could you please provide a sample input and the expected output? Thank you.

Comment: @user12445682 Could you please confirm if the result I posted in the answer is the one you expect. If not, please explain what's wrong so I can improve the answer. Thank you